# Smoothing vertices

Tags: edit-mode

I want to make a wall cable. I used cylinder for that, resized it, subdivided it and lowered some vertices like on the image. But I want it to look smooth without sharp edges. How can I do it?[image]

Comment: Hello :). In this case, your best bet is the [Subdivision modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html). But there are certainly [better ways to make wall cables](https://youtu.be/EVIHttdwes0). Good luck.